# Django - code of HttpRequest class

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

**Answer**

**(1)**
The `read()` method of the `HttpRequest` object (`self`) calls the `read()` method of its `_stream` attribute.
That is, `_stream` is an object of its own class and has its own `read()` method.

**(2)**
The `read()` method of `HttpRequest` objects and of `_stream` are not necessarily the same as the
`read()` of file objects. Thus, they may take different arguments.

**(3)**
`self._stream` must be set by a subclass.

**(3)**
Yes. More precisely, the `@property` decorator means that the method is called whenever we reference
the name, e.g. `self.body`.

*/Thanks to Daniel Roseman for the answers./*



**Question**

I'm going through the code of the `HttpRequest` class of Django.

According to the code below, `self.body()` tries to call `self.read()` and assign its return value to `self._body`.
If no exception, it calls StringIO on self._body and assigns its return value to self._stream.

**I have four related questions:**
**(1)**
Does `self.read()` call itself on `self._stream`? Or does it call the read methodof file objects?

**(2)**
What is the reason for including args and kwargs in the definition of `self.read`?

**(3)**
For what I found in the definition of HttpRequest, `self._stream` is created by the `self.body` method.
What happens when `self.body()` is first called? Supposedly, `self._stream` hasn't been created yet.
To create it, `self.body()` needs to first create `self._body`.
To create self._body, self.read() is called.
But s`elf.read() calls .read() on self._stream`.
So, where does it get self._stream from?

**(4)**
Regardless of the thing that self.body is a property, self.body() method is still called,
and its return value is what we get when we call for self.body. Am I right?

**django.http.HttpRequest**

```
class HttpRequest(object):

    #...

    def __init__(self):
        self.GET, self.POST, self.COOKIES, self.META, self.FILES = {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
        self.path = ''
        self.path_info = ''
        self.method = None
        self._post_parse_error = False

    #...

    @property
    def body(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_body'):
            if self._read_started:
                raise Exception("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
            try:
                self._body = self.read()
            except IOError, e:
                raise UnreadablePostError, e, sys.exc_traceback
            self._stream = StringIO(self._body)
        return self._body

    #...

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._read_started = True
        return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)

    #...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it calls the `read()` method of whatever object `self._stream` is.
2. This is the normal pattern to allow arbitrary arguments (positional and keyword) to be passed into the method. In this case, they are passed directly on to the stream's read method.
3. The comment above that code explains what is going on - self._stream must be set by a subclass.
4. Yes. The `@property` decorator means that you the method is called when you simply reference the name, ie as `self.body` rather than `self.body()`.

Comment: 1. Doesn't read() take only one (size) argument? Isn't it the same read() method as what we use when we open a file? If so, isn't it enough to call it as "self._stream.read(size)"?

Comment: Not necessarily: as I said, it's the `read` method of whatever `self._stream` is. From the above code, that is a StringIO instance, which in that case takes the same parameters - but there's nothing to stop a subclass from using a completely different class which might take more arguments to its read method.